# From-data api create urllib2 in python

Tags: python, urllib2

I have call so many api with the help of urllib2 json type. But now i want to crate from-data api with the help of urllib2 and it is not working

I have post api and url and this data

```
Dummy url =  https://www.example.com/xyz?id=32323232

dummy data {'data': "here"}
```

data should be sent by form-data not raw json type

how can we write code in python with urllib2

Answer (score 0):

```
url =  https://www.example.com/xyz?id=32323232
data = {'data': "here"}
header = {'ContentType' : 'multipart/form-data'}

request = urllib2.Request(url, data, header)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Refer : https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/how-to-use-urllib2-in-python/

Comment: Without the actual url i cannot test out the code myself.. refer the link and try to debug